# Why does Windows 10's Windows Update always automatically reinstall C++ Redistributable 8.0.61000

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have uninstalled it multiple times - each time Windows update runs, it always *automatically* reinstalls that C++ Redistributable Security Update.
The Problem I have with that is:
I am not aware that C++ Redistributable (unfixed) is present on my machine, as otherwise I'd want to get rid of it as well.
I have no indication that *any* of the applications present on my W10 system requires that specific runtime.
How can I uncover/counteract windows installation-dependency-decision-making in that case ?

Comment: The **C++ Redistributable Security Update** would only be installed if the corresponding C++ Redistributable was installed.  It absolutely does not come preinstalled, it is absolutely not an optional update that gets automatically installed, it’s an update that would only be installing

Comment: Do you have QuickBooks installed and updating?  That will cause this and leave the Redistributable update installed. There may be other software that does this as well

Comment: @Ramhound: I figured that much, but ... question to all: how do I get rid of that presumably underlying C++ 2005 x64 Redistributable installation which does not at all show in the windows control panel list of installed software

Comment: Probably the question should be rephrased as "how do I get rid of a suspected *hidden* installation of C++ 2005 x64 Redistributable".

Comment: I am sure I do *not* need the redistributable, because I have a second system with (by intention) identical sw setup (but different install/uninstall history) which does *not* show this strange behaviour.

Comment: @puzzled-guy - Simplest solution would be to install C++ 2005 then uninstall it.